# OpenStreetMap how to identify major ports

Tags: openstreetmap, data, transportation

I'm quite new to OSM data.  Can anyone help me with the best tags to use to identify major shipping ports?  I'd like to be able to identify cities that have a significant amount of commercial shipping activity.  I haven't found this as specific tags, so maybe I need to use something else as a proxy for shipping activity.  I don't know - something like  cities that are harbours and have customs and a lot of docks and cranes, etc etc.

I'd love something a little simpler, if you're able to help.

Comment: I was once given an excel of all ports with tonnage and cargo globally Sorry I cannot remember the source.

Comment: As an alternative to using OpenStreetMap for this you may want to review the answer to http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22036/where-can-i-download-a-free-dataset-containing-major-ports-across-the-world

Comment: @PolyGeo - thanks.  I actually found that a few minutes after posting my question.  I downloaded the dataset and took a quick look, and it might indeed do what I need.

Comment: The *amount of commercial shipping activity* is nothing that belongs into the OSM database. OSM contains (mostly) information that is verifiable on the ground.

Comment: @scai - yes, that is certainly clear that the amount of activity is not something that is going to be in OSM data.  However, it seems reasonable that one could get a rough idea of the amount of commercial activity by counting certain verifiable information (e.g. cranes).  In any case, I think the best solution is in the link posted by PolyGeo

Comment: @susiederkins This is certainly an interesting approach but will probably fail because not all ports are mapped with the same detail in OSM.

Comment: landuse=port or landuse=harbour with overpass-turbo?